# Facebook Like Problem, Same Count for All Posts

Tags: html, facebook, iframe, facebook-like

Right, I've been at this all day and I still can't fix it.

Website: example.com
I am using the iFrame like api with a link like

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fexamle.com&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=80&amp;action=like&amp;font=arial&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;locale=en_US" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:80px; height:30px"></iframe>"
```

or

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fexamle.com&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=80&amp;action=like&amp;font=arial&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;locale=en_US" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:80px; height:30px"></iframe>
```

But they seem to have identical vote values, even if you visit the url directly, does anyone know why?

Many thanks,

---

Even using FB:Like this problem still occurs

```
<fb:like href="http://examle.com" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="80" action="like" font="arial" colorscheme="light" class=" fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget"></fb:like>
```

---

I have added

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Google Nexus S - Black unlocked"/> 
<meta property="og:type" content="product"/> 
<meta property="og:url" content="http://examle.com"/>
```

Yet still it doesn't work? The Lint'er says http://examle.com?

---

The linter now picks up the correct URL, but the Like buttons still all save the same value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was, although the meta tags were on the page, they were very far down in the header which was 100 lines+

This meant Facebook wasn't picking them up, moving the meta tags to the first 5 lines of the document fixed the problem. I guess FB only downloads the top X lines/bytes of your website.

Many thanks to ifaour, for pointing me at the [URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http://www.evotronix.com/motorola-atrix-4g-unlocked)!

P.s. On top of this FB has cached all the previous likes so I had to change all the links slightly (I just added ?n) for it to recognise it as a new link!

Answer (score 3):

You are missing some Open Graph Meta tags: `og:url` and `fb:admins or fb:app_id` refer to [Like Plugin (Open Graph Tags)](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

If you test both urls in the URL Linter, you'll notice that Facebook is capturing the same URL! ([URL1](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http://www.evotronix.com/motorola-atrix-4g-unlocked) - [URL2](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint?url=http://www.evotronix.com/google-nexus-s-unlockedtest))

Comment: Please see my edit, thanks for your help so far. The Linter is still showing the same url?

Comment: @PezCuckow: Okay, try the XFBML version and REMOVE the `href` attribute...I'm seeing people having troubles with the iframe version

Comment: If I removed the href, they would all point to the same page?

Comment: @PezCuckow: No, but the XFBML version defaults to the current page. And facebook will look at the `og:url` tag